# How to loop through all subforms MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a main form with many subforms (and sub-Subforms).  I would like to have a button on my main subform that will toggle each subform from enabled=true to enabled=false. Is it possible to do this without having to specifically refer to each subform?  Maybe something like: For each subform of frmMainForm...?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can loop the controls:

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If Control.ControlType = acSubform Then
        ' Do something with this subform control.
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If Control.ControlType = acSubform Then
        If Control.Name = sSubform Then
            Control.Visible = True
        Else
            Control.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

help4access.com uses this method to turn subforms on/or when many housed with a single main form.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle a boolean setting you set it to `Not` itself. I also give an alternate way to check the type of an object that works for all objects and not just a control that may or may not have a `ControlType` property.

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf Control Is SubForm Then
        Control.Visible = Not Control.Visible
    End If
Next
```